What does #pragma message do?
Using GCC on Linux (Mint)
I have a line of code ...
#pragma message "blah blah blah"

When I run GCC I get this output with no warning, errors, etc ...

src/source_file.c:29:9: note: ‘#pragma message: blah blah blah’
29 | #pragma message "blah blah blah"


I see tutorials specifying how to use #pragma message ... but I didn't know what to expect from compiler output.

It's for adding an info message to the compilation (not an error/warning), so I think that what you get is exactly what it's supposed to be. This post is showing some possible use-cases (although it is not for gcc).

One thing it can be used for is testing preprocessor conditionalization.  If you want to make sure some conditional piece of code is being included, or excluded, you can use this to see.

Note that #error and (in C23 or later) #warning are mandated by the C standard.  #pragma message is not mandated by the standard.  'Tis interesting that the draft 2023 C standard from 2023-04-01 (n3096.pdf) says "§6.10.t ¶1 … Any such pragma that is not recognized by the implementation is ignored".  So does the draft for C2x from 2024-04-22 (n3220.pdf), but it adds "Recommended practice ¶3 Implementations are encouraged to diagnose unrecognized pragmas".

The #pragma is a preprocessor directive that provides additional information to the compiler. They are not part of the core language but allow for various compiler-specific customizations and optimizations. The correct syntax for #pragma message requires the message to be enclosed in parentheses and double quotes.
The pragma message can be used to output a message during compilation. For example if you write in the main.c file :
#pragma message("Compiling " __FILE__)

You should have this output :
Compiling main.c


The GCC documentation for #pragma message shows that the it can be used with or without parentheses.
